# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function display_sess_msg() in index.php on line 148

Tags: php

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function display_sess_msg() in
>   index.php on line 148

I have a strange problem, this error occurs on one of my servers, on the other the script work

The error of 148 is this: `<?=display_sess_msg ();?>`

```
td  valign="top" align="right"><font color="#D0601C"><?=display_sess_msg();?></font></td>
```

**admin/includes/funcs_cur.inc.php**

```
    function display_sess_msg()
{
        if($_SESSION['sess_msg']!=''){
                echo '<div class="redcolor">';
                echo "<br>".$_SESSION['sess_msg'];
                unset($_SESSION['sess_msg']);
                echo "</div>";
        }
}
```

The weird and I'm not finding documentation is that the call is made this way  `<?=display_sess_msg()` without the use of $. Would anyone can say why this
works in Funio and does not work on my Debian server.

Thank you

Comment: Is the call of `display_sess_msg()` in the same file that the function definition?

Comment: add Full source code html file and php file

Comment: you include file `funcs_cur.inc.php` in `index.php ` ?

Comment: trying putting a space after the first short hand tag. `<?= display_sess_msg();?>`

Comment: Also, there is no need to echo it. Just call the function `<? display_sess_msg();?>`

Answer (score 1):

On your server where the error occurred must have been a change in php.ini

Either check that in php.ini

```
short_open_tag = On
```

and restart apache or try using

```
<?php display_sess_msg (); ?>
```

Comment: It shows the error : "Could not connect to database. Please check configuration and ensure MySQL is running."

Comment: if you connect to a database in your script then there is a problem on that @Rohan